SQLAlchemy "db.create_all()" command not adding Boolean column to my database table
I am working on a Flask project, I am trying to make a Database table to store Admin information using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL. Here is my code for the Admin Table.

class AdminModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'admin_table'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                           server_default=func.now())
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    is_authenthicated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    is_logedin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def is_authenthicated(self):
        return self.is_authenthicated

    def is_admin(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def is_logedin(self):
        return self.is_logedin

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<FirstName {self.first_name}>'

To create the table in the database I'm doing it by command line with the following commands.
>>> From app import db, AdminModel
>>> db.drop_all()
>>> db.create_all()

Problem
It creates the table and adds the Columns except for the Boolean column (is_authenthicated, is_admin, is_logedin) that I have defined in the model. I don't know why it's happening at first it was adding only one Boolean column but now it's not adding any Boolean column to my database table I have tried multiple times to drop and recreate the table but it's not working. Even if I add another string column after the Boolean columns it will add that but not the Boolean. I tried to make a migration using Flask-Migrate but it is also not detecting any changes.
My database table in PgAdmin looks like this

Any solution. Need Help

don't use the same name for both the columns and the functions, use different names
